# If else statement not outputting correctly?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm a beginner to Python and am struggling with a project I am working on. The program takes monthly income, fixed monthly expenses, asks for any additional expenses, and then outputs with an if else statement. My issue is in this function:

```
def spending(income, totals):

  finalTotal = income - totals

  if income > finalTotal:

    print("You saved $", "%.2f"%finalTotal, "this month!")
  elif finalTotal > income:

    print("You overspent by $", "%.2f"%finalTotal, "this month!")

  else:

    print("You broke even this month!")
```

It is printing:

```
You saved $ -805.00 this month!
```

When I'd like it to print:

```
You overspent by $ 805.00 this month!
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my code:
https://replit.com/@ashleyshubin/BudgetProgram#main.py

Comment: It's unrelated to your main question (about the `if`/`elif` conditions), but your formatting is a bit weird in the `print` calls. There's no reason to split the `%.2f` into its own string just for the formatting. You could use `"You saved $%.2f this month!" % finalTotal`, or better, do something similar with `str.format` (or an f-string).

Answer (score 1):

If totals is your monthly expenses, then subtracting totals from income gives you how much money you made this month. The first if statement should be

```
if finalTotal > 0:
```

The second if statement would be

```
if finalTotal < 0:
```

And you would want to use abs(finalTotal) when printing finalTotal so it does not display a negative number

Answer (score 0):

Your checks are wrong. You can do the following:

```
def spending(income, totals):
  finalTotal = income - totals
  if income > totals:
    print("You saved $", "%.2f"%finalTotal, "this month!")
  elif totals > income:
    print("You overspent by $", "%.2f"%-finalTotal, "this month!")
  else:
    print("You broke even this month!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This section is where it is going wrong:

```
finalTotal = income - totals
  if income > finalTotal:
    print("You saved $", "%.2f"%finalTotal, "this month!")
```

It looks like you're comparing the wrong variables in your "if" statement. your "finalTotal" variable already includes your income. Think of it like alegbra, and replace "finalTotal" with "income - totals", and your if statement now looks like:

```
    if income > (income - totals):
```

this statement will always evaluate to true, no matter what values you are using. You probably want to rewrite your if statements to compare "income > totals", rather than finalTotal.

Answer (score 0):

your comparison shoud be based on finaltotal , as fianaltotal is `finalTotal = income - totals`, also `else`  never runs based on the other conditions in your code:

```
def spending(income, totals):
    finalTotal = income - totals
    if finalTotal > 0:
        print("You saved $", "%.2f" % finalTotal, "this month!")
    else:
        print("You overspent by $", "%.2f" % abs(finalTotal), "this month!")
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be comparing Income with total spends.

```
def spending(income, totals):

  finalTotal = abs(income - totals)

  if totals < income:

    print("You saved $", "%.2f"%finalTotal, "this month!")
  elif totals > income:

    print("You overspent by $", "%.2f"%finalTotal, "this month!")

  else:

    print("You broke even this month!")
```